# How can I add 2 Title elements side by side using Angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, titlebar, mat-expansion-panel

In my project I am using `<mat-expansion-panel>`. I am trying to add `2 title element` using `<mat-panel-title>` side by side with their `respective description`

Currently my code displays

`Title1 Title2 Description1 Description2`

What I am looking for is

`Title1 Description1 Title2 Description2`

Here is my code - Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-q1qxz7?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Title 1 </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <dd class="col-sm-10 record_property_value" data-property-type="select">{{ 'Description fror Title 1'}}</dd>
      </mat-panel-description>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Title 2
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <dd class="col-sm-10 record_property_value" data-property-type="select">{{ 'Description fror Title 2'}}</dd>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: A single panel header may have only 1 `mat-panel-title` and 1 `mat-panel-description`. Why do you need to have a panel with double titles and their descriptions?

Comment: Requirement is to display both `Title 1` and `Title 2` with their `description` on `main element`. As of now I was showing `Title 2 and its description` when `expansion panel ` was `opened`. For `readability` purpose trying to show both `data` on `main component`. Is there any other way I can make this possible? Thanks

Comment: this is just to play along wrap them in 2 divs Div1 = title1+desc1 and Div2=title2+desc2. You should consider implementing a custom header if you have some exceptional requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Angular material documentation, `mat-expansion-panel-header` should have a single `<mat-panel-title>` and an `<mat-panel-description>` for proper positioning of panel content. But in your case you can try this method...

I have edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-hgtl61?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html) here and it seems to be working. Please verify..